# OnClick event not fired in javascript when attached to img

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I'm new to JavaScript, so this may be basic...

I'm trying to create an image dynamically and add it a event listener for "onclick". I add this `img` to a `div`.

I create the img like this:

```
function createNewSmiley()
{
    var newSmiley = document.createElement("img");
    newSmiley.src = "./smiley.jpg";
    newSmiley.alt = "Smiley Image";
    newSmiley.style.width = "64px";
    newSmiley.style.height = "64px";
    return newSmiley;
}
```

And then I add it to the div like using like this:

```
function positionNewSmiley(parent, smiley, x, y)
{
    var newSmiley = createNewSmiley();
    newSmiley.style.top = y + "px";
    newSmiley.style.left = x + "px";
    parent.appendChild(newSmiley);
}
```

And this is my main function:

```
function main(smileyCount)
{
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
    for (var i = 0; i < smileyCount;i++)
    {
        var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 500));
        var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 500));
        var smiley = createNewSmiley();
        smiley.onclick = smileyClicked;
        positionNewSmiley(myDiv, smiley, x, y);
    }
}

function smileyClicked(ev) {
    alert("OK");
}
```

But the `onclick` event will not fire!

however, if I add the event listener to the div - it will.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `positionNewSmiley()` creates a new object (without the click handler) and only that one is added to the document.

Comment: How did I miss this? thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the above comment you're creating new `smiley` in the `positionNewSmiley` when you've to position the passed `smiley` instead :

```
var smiley = createNewSmiley();
smiley.onclick = smileyClicked;

positionNewSmiley(myDiv, smiley, x, y);
_________________________^^^^^^
```

Just use it in the position function :

```
function positionNewSmiley(parent, smiley, x, y)
{
    smiley.style.top = y + "px";
    smiley.style.left = x + "px";

    parent.appendChild(smiley);
}
```

Hope this helps.

```js
function createNewSmiley()
{
  var newSmiley = document.createElement("img");
  newSmiley.src = "http://cfile24.uf.tistory.com/image/163BB51F4BF9DF7431AB10";
  newSmiley.alt = "Smiley Image";
  newSmiley.style.width = "64px";
  newSmiley.style.height = "64px";

  return newSmiley;
}


function positionNewSmiley(parent, smiley, x, y)
{
  smiley.style.top = y + "px";
  smiley.style.left = x + "px";

  parent.appendChild(smiley);
}

function main(smileyCount)
{
  var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");

  for (var i = 0; i < smileyCount;i++)
  {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 500));
    var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 500));
    var smiley = createNewSmiley();
    smiley.onclick = smileyClicked;
    positionNewSmiley(myDiv, smiley, x, y);
  }
}

function smileyClicked(ev) {
  alert("OK");
}

main(6);
```

```html
<div id='myDiv'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you add the on click within the create function it will work

```
    function createNewSmiley()
{
    var newSmiley = document.createElement("img");
    newSmiley.src = "./smiley.jpg";
    newSmiley.alt = "Smiley Image";
    newSmiley.style.width = "64px";
    newSmiley.style.height = "64px";
    newSmiley.addEventListener("click", smileyClicked);
    return newSmiley;
}
```